# Howto enable Quick diff with plus and minus in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

i had a eclipse workspace. I used Galileo and Subclipse. I got the workspace from a associate. The following function was enabled:

There were signs shown to indicate differences to the svn state of the document, directly right beside the line numbers. If I added a line a "+" were shown. If I deleted a line a "-" were shown and a "~" when I edited a line.

I think this is much easier than the colored quick diff. Now I had to install the hole system again. I installed Eclipse Galileo and Subclipse again. Now I can't find the settings to enable this feature anymore.

How do I enable it?
Is this called Quick Diff, too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is under the Accessibility preferences.

General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Accessibility -> Use Characters to show changes in the vertical ruler.